# Where can i find jquery plugin like twitter bootstrap's .subnav auto float bar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-plugins

when u see this page

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html

there's an auto float bar at where u scroll your page it auto stick to top

where can i find a plugin and got many custom settings like this ?

i've copy the html and javascript code from that page like below

```
(function($){

    var $win = $(window);
    var $nav = $('.subnav');
    var navTop = $('.subnav').length && $('.subnav').offset().top - 38;
    var isFixed = 0;

    processScroll();

    $win.on('scroll', processScroll);

    function processScroll() {
        console.log('test');
        var i, scrollTop = $win.scrollTop();
        if (scrollTop >= navTop && !isFixed) {
            isFixed = 1;
            $nav.addClass('subnav-fixed');
        } else if (scrollTop <= navTop && isFixed) {
            isFixed = 0;
            $nav.removeClass('subnav-fixed');
        }
    };

})(jQuery);
```

but it just can't move and stick to top

Comment: this code seems to work fine for me. The only piece it doesn't do is the scroll spy menu highlighting.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you incorporate the css as well as the html/javascript.
The `subnav-fixed` class is useless without the accompanying css in your stylesheet.

Copied from the site (via firebug) :

```
.subnav-fixed {
    /*important part*/
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 40px;
    z-index: 1020;
    /*design stuff*/
    border-color: #D5D5D5;
    border-radius: 0 0 0 0;
    border-width: 0 0 1px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #FFFFFF inset, 0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

Comment: I've copy all CSS prefix with subnav seems when I scroll page it won't add subnavfixed class to subnav